# How to keep `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from getting overwritten to pwd when running python script

Tags: linux, bash, python, environment-variables, shared-libraries

I have a python script which eventually calls a binary that requires certain shared libraries. However, I have been running into the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_rt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have narrowed down the cause of this error to the fact that python overwrites `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to be the PWD. When executing the binary manually via the bash, everything works properly as this environment variable is properly set. Here are examples of the current behavior:

```bash
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/the/proper/paths
```

```bash
$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.environ.get('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
/the/proper/paths
```

```bash
$ python script.py
/my/present/working/directory
```

Here, `script.py` has the same contents as the second example.

Other information asked for:

```
$ which python
~/.pyenv/shims/python
$ python --version
Python 3.7.3
$ type python
python is hashed (/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/shims/python)
$ realpath `which python`
/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/shims/python
```

I would like to know if there's a way to see where this variable is getting changed and/or why this would be happening.

I am aware that I could simply hard-code the in the script, but that is a band-aid solution, I would rather know exactly what is happening under the hood.

Comment: Can't reproduce. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is correct in both cases. Why `echo` in `$ echo python` in second example? Typo? Is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` exported? `python --version`? `type python`? `realpath \`which python\``?

Comment: @dimich yeah that was a typo and I have updated the prompt with the information you asked for.

Comment: `~/.pyenv/shims/python` is a shell script which invokes another shell script, in my system it is `/usr/share/pyenv/libexec/pyenv`. That script also processes some plugins and hook directories. Likely you problem is not with python itself but with `pyenv` package and it's configuration.

Comment: You can trace which process changes environment variable, e.g. using [this shell script](https://gist.github.com/dimich-dmb/f25a7ec41d599e0b5e0bd639f24d7001#file-envtrace-sh). In python run something like `subprocess.run(["/path/to/envtrace.sh", "LD_LIBRARY_PATH"])`

Comment: @dimich does this script allow the tracking of this env var while I run a python script? I found around where it happens, but this would greatly help narrow it down.

Comment: No, sorry, it can't track change of variable in realtime. It just shows the value of variable in environments of parent processes up to `init` at the moment of invocation.

Answer (score 1):

> I am aware that I could simply hard-code the in the script, but that is a band-aid solution, I would rather know exactly what is happening under the hood.

What's happening under the hood is that some code in your `script.py` (or code which `script.py` imports) sets the environment variable.

You can run `gdb --args python script.py`, set a breakpoint on `setenv` and `putenv`, and have GDB stop the program when the environment is reset. However, this will stop somewhere in the Python runtime, and figuring out which Python code is running might get tricky.

---

That said, setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is *not* the right way to fix the "binary that requires certain shared libraries" problem in the first place.

A much better solution is to either link the binary with correct `-rpath` flag, or to fix already-linked binary using `patchelf --set-rpath`, so the binary runs correctly *without* `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: So it seems that the env var gets overwritten after a specific import in my script. However, nowhere in the script I am importing is there a portion that is playing around with environment variables. (I checked that the value was maintained throughout). wondering if this could be a thing with `import`? -- Also, I was using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` because that is how the executable is shipped and told to be set up - it's not something I wrote.